# Reallocate block of allocated memory different than its offset

Tags: c, memory-management, realloc

What will happen if I reallocate a specific block of memory of a previously allocated memory area?

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *area = malloc(15 + 1);

    strcpy(area, "Stack / Overflow");
    realloc(area + 5, strlen(area) + 5);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Will the `area` string be expanded with 5 bytes in this example?

```
Idx: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
Chr: S  t  a  c  k  \0 \0 \0 \0 \0     /       O   v   e   r   f   l   o   w   \0
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass `area+5` to `realloc`, since `area+5` is not pointing to the address of a memory segment previously allocated with `malloc` or with `realloc` (which is the basic constraint of the first argument passed to `realloc`).

Comment: It will invoke undefined behavior.  Don't do that.

Comment: You allocate 16 bytes and try to store 17 characters in `area`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Undefined behaviour. `realloc()` needs a pointer returned by `malloc()` or family or a `NULL`.

As per the `c99`, chapter 7.20.3.4, paragraph 3, for `void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);` [emphasis mine]

> If ptr is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the
>   specified size. Otherwise, **if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by the
>   calloc, malloc, or realloc function**, or if the space has been deallocated by a call
>   to the free or realloc function, **the behavior is undefined**. If memory for the new
>   object cannot be allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

---

Other than this, in your code

```
char *area = malloc(15 + 1);
strcpy(area, "Stack / Overflow");
```

you're not allocating space for terminating null. Result *can* be devastating. Please add space to store terminating `\0`.

<strike>Also, while using [`realloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc), please notice the second parameter. It should be the *new* size [in total], ***not*** the difference from the *current* allocation size.</strike> [Code snippet updated by OP]

Again, you have to use the return value of `realloc()` to access the newly allocated memory. The old pointer *may* not be valid anymore. Please read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) for details.

So for you, the code should look like

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *area = malloc(17);   //space for terminating null
    char * area_next = NULL;


    strcpy(area, "Stack / Overflow");   //cpy 16 chars, with null
    area_next = realloc(area, 23);                  // oldsize + 5

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It can also be `NULL` as far as I recall (though I did not mention that in my comment to the question).

Comment: So undefined behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos indeed, it behaves like `malloc` when it's first parameter is `NULL` it's obviously very convenient.

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks sir, updated with related information. :-)

Comment: I forgot to add the total amount, passed as second arg to `realloc`

Comment: @AlanSalios That's not the only thing to notice. See my updated answer.

Comment: @AlanSalios Sorry, I forgot to add _Please_, updated. Should be ok I hope. :-)

Comment: @AlanSalios `Please remove the part with the total amount of new bytes reallocated note` This time i did not get you. What's the point?

Comment: Well, I edited my question so this note is no longer related to the question. To improve the quality of the question by not confusing other people, please remove that pair `Also, while using realloc(), please notice the second parameter. It should be the new size [in total], not the difference from the current allocation size.`:)

Comment: @AlanSalios Well, AFAIK, you should not edit the question in a way that makes the already existing answer invalid. This time I'll do the cleanup, but just in case, keep in mind next time onwards, ok? Cheers !!

Comment: Yes, that's right. I am not supposed to do that. It just happened meanwhile your answer as it was quite fast. Thank you.

Comment: Render unto `free()` only what `malloc()` rendered unto thee. Oh and family including `calloc()` and `realloc()` but you get the point.

Answer (score 0):

The heap manager when allocates a memory blocks keep track of each allocated chunk in order to handle successive reallocations or releases of chunks.
So the memory allocator knows very well which memory belongs to it and could be legally resized or released (normally the manager for each allocation builds also an hidden control block where are saved all block properties).
While the standards C99 C11 still assume an **undefined behavior** for invalid pointers actually almost all C & C++ libraries implementations throw an exception in such a case.